# How would I parse this section of an OBJ file?

Tags: parsing, rust, .obj

I am trying to parse this

```
    f 3//2 8//2 4//2
    f 7//3 6//3 8//3
    f 2//4 8//4 6//4
    f 1//5 4//5 2//5
    f 5//6 2//6 6//6
    f 5//1 7//1 3//1
    f 3//2 7//2 8//2
    f 7//3 5//3 6//3
    f 2//4 4//4 8//4
    f 1//5 3//5 4//5
    f 5//6 1//6 2//6
```

in Rust, but I'm not sure how. I want it to be that it is split so that the numbers *before* the double slashes get put into the **x,y,z** components of a `Vec4`, and the number *after* gets put in the **w** component (i.e. `f 3//2 8//2 4//2` -> `Vec4::new(3,8,4,2);`)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I'm new to Rust, and honestly have no idea where to start. @ChayimFriedman

Comment: You can always try [regex](https://crates.io/crates/regex).

Comment: I wrote an OBJ parser once. You can take a look at its particular solution [here](https://github.com/rodrigorc/papercraft/blob/main/src/waveobj/mod.rs#L72). I do a `line.split_whitespace()` and then for each word a `word.split('/')`. Finally a `parse<usize>()` to convert each piece to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should really be solved with regex. Something like `f (\d+)//(\d+) (\d+)//(\d+) (\d+)//(\d+)` should do the trick where capture groups 1, 3, 4 are 0, 1, 2 in your vector and 2, 3, 5 should be asserted to all be the same then go into the the last place.

But parsing strings in rust is always fun, so here's my crack at it.
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=52441e70033a3956f5914c5288202386

Comment: Thanks for the regex, I'll probably end up using that! I just have one issue: When I tried the regex in the RegExr Playground it worked fine, but I got an error when trying it in the Rust playground. Some issue with the "/\". Do you know how I may fix this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't need to escape them in rust - my mistake.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=46ad30ab66772636bf4d396931ebbda4